# Swift CocoaPod is clickable but not findable for Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rsbarcodes

I use the CocoaPod `RSBarcodes_Swift` to work with barcodes. The installation was successful and if I open the *.xcworkspace file I can see the source files for the pod.

**The problem:**

If I'm typing lines like `class FirstViewController: RSCodeReaderViewController` Xcode cannot include / find / use this view controller class but nevertheless, I can Cmd+Click on the word to jump to the actual file. The same happens if I try to use statements like `import RSBarcodes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never trust a web's manual. You have to use the import statement:

`import RSBarcodes_Swift`

Now it seams to work. My lessons learned: Understand in which cases you have to use an import statement and in which cases not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build the project, you need to build the imported CocoaPods modules to use in your projects. Press CMD + R. Import and use the classes.